# How to exclude data by users' id in Google Analytics > Behavior > Events?

Tags: google-analytics

Is it possible to exclude certain events by users' id?

Here I don't see it in dimensions:
[image]

I see here a filter but it only offers to filter by columns listed below:
[image]

Is there really no such an option, must I slap a user id on every event I send to analytics?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

user ID and client ID couldn't be used for filtering in reports or segments to do that. However, you might set up a custom tracking and store the user ID value as custom dimension so it will be possible to use it in reports later.
Check this guide for more information https://www.simoahava.com/analytics/13-useful-custom-dimensions-for-google-analytics/

Comment: So, I am supposed to send user id through this custom dimension with every event, e.g. view_item event?

Comment: you'd be fine setting a custom dimension to `session` level and then sending it's value just once per session